# Revits system browser into autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

[Revit system browser] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubi2Y.png)

I am unable to bring the Revit system browser into forge. The image I attached is the system browser.

I tried with few codes to bring the system browser. Unable to get it into the system browser.....

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Model Derivative API only extracts common Revit data into SVF/SVF2, not all Revit data will be there (e.g. System relationships).

However, if you just want to show the system hierarchy like the system browser, not all functionalities of the system browser. Here is a starting point for you, which lists all MEP systems shown on the system browser.

==== /// the old answer here was deleted, please check the new answer below ====

After discussing with my colleague Joao, we combined our codes together to make the tree structure look more similar to Revit System Browser. However, this sample doesn't fold systems like Revit, but you could change that by modifying the codes to group systems by `Supply From,` `Panel,` or equipment.

Here is the modified code. For the completed code sample, please refer to https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/adding-systems-browser-viewer

```js
async getSystemsData(model) {
  // First we grab all MEP Systems for classifications
  let systems = await getSystems(model);
  let SYSTEMS_DATA = {
    name: 'Systems',
    path: 'systems',
    dbIds: [],
    entries: []
  };

  // Here we grab all the leaf nodes
  const leafNodeDbIds = await this.findLeafNodes(model);
  // Here we retrieve system-related properties for the leaf nodes
  let leafNodeResults = await this.getBulkPropertiesAsync(model, leafNodeDbIds, { propFilter: [SYSTEM_TYPE_PROPERTY, SYSTEM_NAME_PROPERTY, SYSTEM_CIRCUIT_NUMBER_PROPERTY, 'name', 'Category'] });
  leafNodeResults = leafNodeResults.filter(e => e.properties.length >= 2);

  for (const system of systems) {
    //For each MEP systems we retrieve its properties
    let systemName = system.name;
    let familyNameProp = system.properties.find(p => p.attributeName == REVIT_FAMILY_NAME_PROPERTY);
    // Here we transform system name to correct classifications
    let systemClassificationName = getSystemClassification(familyNameProp?.displayValue);

    //And then we start populating the SYSTEMS_DATA object
    let currentSystemClassification = SYSTEMS_DATA.entries.find(s => s.name == systemClassificationName);
    if (!currentSystemClassification) {
      SYSTEMS_DATA.entries.push({ name: systemClassificationName, path: `systems/${systemClassificationName}`, dbIds: [], entries: [] });
      currentSystemClassification = SYSTEMS_DATA.entries.find(s => s.name == systemClassificationName);
    }

    let currentSystem = null;
    if (systemClassificationName == 'Electrical') {
      currentSystem = currentSystemClassification;
    } else {
      currentSystem = currentSystemClassification.entries.find(s => s.name == systemName);
      if (!currentSystem) {
        currentSystemClassification.entries.push({ name: systemName, path: `systems/${systemClassificationName}/${systemName}`, dbIds: [], entries: [] });
        currentSystem = currentSystemClassification.entries.find(s => s.name == systemName);
      }
    }

    // Here we grab all MEP System types and their system-related properties
    let systemTypeDbIds = system.properties.filter(p => p.attributeName == CHILD_PROPERTY).map(p => p.displayValue);
    let systemTypeResults = await this.getBulkPropertiesAsync(model, systemTypeDbIds, { propFilter: [SYSTEM_TYPE_PROPERTY, SYSTEM_NAME_PROPERTY, SYSTEM_CIRCUIT_NUMBER_PROPERTY, 'name'] });

    for (let systemTypeResult of systemTypeResults) {
      //For system type we retrieve properties for the leaf nodes
      let systemTypeTypeProp = systemTypeResult.properties.find(p => p.attributeName == SYSTEM_TYPE_PROPERTY);
      let systemTypeNameProp = systemTypeResult.properties.find(p => p.attributeName == SYSTEM_NAME_PROPERTY);
      let circuitNumberProp = systemTypeResult.properties.find(p => p.attributeName == SYSTEM_CIRCUIT_NUMBER_PROPERTY);

      let systemTypeName = systemTypeNameProp?.displayValue;
      let systemTypeEntryPath = `systems/${systemClassificationName}/${systemName}/${systemTypeName}`;
      if (systemClassificationName == 'Electrical') {
        systemTypeName = systemTypeTypeProp?.displayValue;
        systemTypeEntryPath = `systems/${systemClassificationName}/${systemTypeName}`;
      }

      let currentSystemType = currentSystem.entries.find(st => st.name == systemTypeName);
      if (!currentSystemType) {
        currentSystem.entries.push({ name: systemTypeName, path: systemTypeEntryPath, dbIds: [], entries: [] });
        currentSystemType = currentSystem.entries.find(st => st.name == systemTypeName);
      }

      // Here we retrieve system-end elements by their system type value from the leaf nodes
      let endElementResults = null;
      let prevCurrentSystemType = null;
      if (systemClassificationName == 'Electrical') {
        let circuitNumberVal = circuitNumberProp?.displayValue;
        let currentCircuitNumber = currentSystemType.entries.find(st => st.name == circuitNumberVal);
        if (!currentCircuitNumber) {
          currentSystemType.entries.push({ name: circuitNumberVal, path: `${systemTypeEntryPath}/${circuitNumberVal}`, dbIds: [], entries: [] });
          currentCircuitNumber = currentSystemType.entries.find(st => st.name == circuitNumberVal);
        }

        prevCurrentSystemType = currentSystemType;
        currentSystemType = currentCircuitNumber;
        let endElementSearchTerm = SYSTEM_CIRCUIT_NUMBER_PROPERTY;
        endElementResults = leafNodeResults.filter(e =>
          (e.properties.find(prop => prop.attributeName == endElementSearchTerm && prop.displayValue == currentSystemType.name) != null)
        );
      } else {
        let endElementSearchTerm = SYSTEM_NAME_PROPERTY;
        endElementResults = leafNodeResults.filter(e =>
          (e.properties.find(prop => prop.attributeName == endElementSearchTerm && prop.displayValue.split(',').some(s => s == currentSystemType.name)) != null)
        );
      }

      for (let endElement of endElementResults) {
        // Each system-end element we put it into correct system type
        let endElementName = endElement.name;
        let currentEndElement = currentSystemType.entries.find(st => st.name == endElementName);
        if (!currentEndElement) {
          currentSystemType.entries.push({ name: endElementName, path: `${currentSystemType}/${endElementName}`, dbIds: [endElement.dbId], entries: [] });
          currentEndElement = currentSystemType.entries.find(st => st.name == endElementName);
        }
        currentSystemType.dbIds.push(endElement.dbId);
        prevCurrentSystemType?.dbIds.push(endElement.dbId);
        currentSystem.dbIds.push(endElement.dbId);
        currentSystemClassification.dbIds.push(endElement.dbId);
      }

      // Remove unused system types for electrical system as Revit does
      if (currentSystemType.entries.length <= 0 && prevCurrentSystemType != null) {
        let idx = prevCurrentSystemType.entries.indexOf(currentSystemType);
        if (idx != -1)
          prevCurrentSystemType.entries.splice(idx, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  return SYSTEMS_DATA;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here's a sample on that: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/adding-systems-browser-viewer